# How to call dot for Eigen::Array

Tags: eigen, eigen3

I have to matrices and would like to treat them as a 1-D list and do a dot product. I the following, but it is not working:

```
Eigen::MatrixXf a(9,9), b(9,9);
float r = a.array().dot(b.array());
```

What would be the best way to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Computing the coefficient-wise product of 2 matrices is a common pattern, so Eigen provides the cwiseProduct() method to write it elegantly. This would lead to the following expression:

```
float r = a.cwiseProduct(b).sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. :)

```cpp
Eigen::MatrixXf a(9, 9), b(9, 9);

Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXf> aVector(a.data(), 81);
Eigen::Map<Eigen::VectorXf> bVector(b.data(), 81);

float squareError = aVector.dot(bVector);
```

Here is [documentation about Map](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1Map.html).

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found it out:

```
float r = (a.array()*b.array()).sum();
```